# file_get_contents(), wget, ping, or curl Timing Out

Tags: php, networking, cron, wget, ping

I am having a strange issue that I have never seen before.  I have been running a cron job with file_get_contents() in PHP on a specific domain for 6 months, and it was working fine.  Now, suddenly, the connection times out almost every time it runs, but not every time.  Sometimes it works, sometimes not.  I am able to access the URL via my personal browser just fine, as well as multiple other computers via browser.

We tried a wget on the URL, and it identified 4 IP addresses for that URL.  1 of them worked for the wget.  The other 3 did not.

Ping did not work.

Curl responds just like file_get_contents().  Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I'm not a network guy, but I'm guessing that this is a network issue?  What do you think the issue is?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it legal to get the contents from that page?

Comment: Yes, we are communicating with a partner server to server postback

Comment: I might add, the partner indicates they are not blocking connections from us.

Comment: are you pinging/wgetting/file_get_contents'ing by IP or hostname?

Comment: We have tried it on both.  The hostname fails almost every time.  By IP address, one of them works every time.  The others fail almost every time.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the comments to your questions, your partner seems to do round-robin DNS with 3 out of 4 invalid IP addresses. Your DNS resolver has a chance of 75% to get the wrong IP and will probably also cache it.

Your partner needs to fix the broken DNS entries and everything should work fine again. In the meantime I suggest using the working IP address.

**Edit**

Since you seem to be able to use all 4 IPs from home, there are a few possible problem areas:

- DNS: run `nslookup your-partners-site.com` and compare the output the what you are getting on your machine.
- Routing: run a traceroute to each IP and compare outputs.
- Firewall: is there any kind of firewall in between the servers that you know of?

You might need the assistance of your partner to make sure it is not an asymmetric issue.

Comment: I have tried all 4 IP addresses in my personal browser from home, and they were all valid and loaded for me.  It seems they are not invalid IP addresses.  Do you still think it's an issue on their end?

Comment: do you have shell access on the server where your cronjob runs?

Comment: Thanks or all the help guys.  To answer your question, yes I have shell access.  But I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to run nslookup and traceroute from shell on my machine.

Comment: if you are on windows: `nslookup` is actually the same and `traceroute` is `tracert`

Comment: Ok I tried nslookup from home and got this response: http://www.josielovesjohn.com/nshome.txt.  Next I tried it from SSH and got this response: http://www.josielovesjohn.com/nsserver.txt.  The IPs appear to be the same.  Do you see anything else that might be causing the issue?

Comment: Traceroute is timing out when I try it on my home machine via command prompt.

Comment: I also received this message from my host if it helps: 

We receive an error anytime the script attempts to return the wget on 174.140.51.21 and the other IP Address
Whenever it attempts to perform a wget on  174.140.33.100 and 174.140.36.21, the process completes.

We believe that your issue is not with the script, but with how CNAME and how the domain DNS is setup.  Unfortunately, this is the most investigation that we can perform on this issue.  As of now, there are no blocks on our end.

Comment: What happens if you run `wget <ip>` on each of the 4 addresses from the server? What's the console output?

Comment: I will post the file with results shortly.  However, so far, here are the results.

174.140.29.100 - success
174.140.33.100 - success
174.140.36.21 - time out fail
174.140.51.21 - time out fail

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once which I could fix sending a HTTP-User-Agent using the curl request.
I used the user agent from my browser, which works fine since then.

Cheers

Comment: I just tried adding the user agent, and it still isn't working for some reason.  See code below.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website');
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

Comment: Hm... was worth a shot.
Try traceroute from your server to the target server multiple times, and compare the results. Maybe you get a timeout and see where it comes from.